# how to count all rows within the tables on a database then display in a textbox?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am a newbie in vb.net so I don't know how to do with this, I was trying to display the sum of the counted rows of a table from my database and it will be displayed in a textbox but after the execution it didn't show in the textbox, I don't know where I've got it wrong even though it doesn't have an error.

so far this is my code:

```
connect.Open()
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
    Dim row As String
    row = "Select count(ISBN) from tbl_book_info"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(row, connect)
    READER = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each rowcount As DataTable In dataset.Tables
        count += rowcount.Rows.Count()
        TextBox7.Text = count.ToString
    Next
    connect.Close()
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: There are ***many issues at hand here***, not just one. You need to call `.Read` on your reader for example, otherwise you will not read anything. No need to loop either as you should only return a scalar value that is your count... Make sure to `Dispose` of your objects as well, don't leave them in the yard... Where is `dataset.Tables` coming from; you are not `Filling` one in which you would do from a `DataAdapter`? As you can see there are many issues, that is just a few of them. I would honestly start over and work your way down.

Comment: That DataAdapter is not used,  If you usd `cmd.ExecuteScalar();` for the Count query., it will return the number of rows.  No loop on something else needed.

Comment: The dupe link provides a more complete/better answer

Comment: @Plutonix is correct, but the link he posted is for `SQL` ***not*** `MySQL`. In this case just replace the `SQL` parts with the `MySQL` equivalent.